# Explicit List cast wrong type?

Tags: c#, casting, explicit

I'm trying to cast to a List from a result from a stored procedure .. I have already created the explicit (working) cast for a single object of ***timerangeResult -> Booking***, but I am missing a list ..

**Here's the code:**

```
public static explicit operator List<Booking>(timerangeResult t)
{
List<Booking> bL = new List<Booking>();
IEnumerable<timerangeResult> tx = (IEnumerable<timerangeResult>) t;

foreach (timerangeResult tt in tx)
{
 Booking b = (Booking)tt;
        bL.Add(b);
}
//return bL;
//return new List<Booking>(bL);
//return new List<Booking>(IEnumerable < Booking > bL);
return bL;
// [NONE OF THESE WORK]
// ERROR:
// User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type (UNDERLINED: "explicit operator List<Booking>" line 1)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Really weird code, you cast a `timerangeResult` to `IEnumerable<timerangeResult>`.

Answer (score 3):

A cast operator needs to be defined in one of the two types involved. Either in the source operand type, or in the destination operand type.

In other words, you need to define the operator either in:

- `List<Booking>` (which is impossible)
- ... or `timerangeResult`

My guess is that you've defined the operator somewhere else, try moving it to the `timerangeResult` type.

Also, note that explicit operators are hard to discover, you really need to know they're there. It's usually much better to add an instance method that does the same thing, ie.:

```
public class timerangeResult
{
    ...

    public List<Booking> ToBookingList()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Lasse, thanks for your quick reply. I've defined this code in Booking.cs.

Comment: Then you need to move it. You can only add cast operators that cast to or from `Booking`, inside `Booking`.

Answer (score 0):

What type is the operator defined in? That operator can only be defined in the `timerangeResult` class (since `List<Booking>`, the other option, is outside your control)

Answer (score 0):

**This is what I got now** (db.designer.cs)

```
public partial class timerangeResult
{

    private int _ID;

    private string _Login;

    private System.DateTime _Starts;

    private System.DateTime _Ends;

    private string _Delete;

    private byte _Notify;

// CUSTOM
//public static explicit operator List<Booking>(timerangeResult t)
public static List<Booking> ToBookingList(IEnumerable<timerangeResult> t)
{
    List<Booking> bL = new List<Booking>();

    foreach (timerangeResult tt in t)
    {
        Booking b = (Booking)tt;
        bL.Add(b);
    }
    return bL;
}
// CUSTOM END^
```

**and .. Booking.cs**

```
public static List<Booking> Today(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
{
    try
    {
        dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();

        IEnumerable<timerangeResult> bQ = from b in db.timerange(begin, end)
                             select b;
        List<Booking> bL = timerangeResult.ToBookingList(bQ);

        return bL;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Now I get: **"The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."**